# Why is the JSP not found in Spring ? File exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

In a very basic app, I have the sayHelloController.java as following

```
@Controller
public class SayHelloController {


    @RequestMapping("say-hello-jsp")
    public String sayHelloJsp() {
        return "sayHello";
    }
}
```

with the following application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
logging.level.org.springframwork=debug
```

and the sayHello.jsp:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        My first JSP file!
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>
            This is the text we want to show <br/>
        <p>
    </body>
 </html>
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/say-hello-jsp, I get a 404 and the logs give me :

```
: GET "/say-hello-jsp", parameters={}
: Mapped to com.in28minutes.springboot.myfirstwebapp.hello.SayHelloController#sayHelloJsp()
: Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
: View name 'sayHello', model {}
: Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/sayHello.jsp]
: "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/WEB-INF/jsp/sayHello.jsp", parameters={}
: Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
: "Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/jsp/sayHello.jsp]"
: Resource not found
```

Which does not make sense, because the file exists, proof :

```
macbook-air:jsp gerald$ pwd
/Users/gerald/IdeaProjects/myfirstwebapp/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp
macbook-air:jsp gerald$ ls
sayHello.jsp
```

Also, I've added jasper as a dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Why is the file not retrieved ?

Comment: What does the rest of your configuration look like? The view shouldn't be getting handled by `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`.

Comment: Which configuration file do you want to see ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158125/Spring-boot-run-configuration-does-not-find-resources-in-META-INF , thanks Andy Wilkinson:

> The problem is that Jasper is marked as provided in the pom so it's
> not on the classpath. I believe there's already an IDEA issue open for
> that problem. It causes Spring Boot to go down a code path where
> various JSP-related bits and pieces are not enabled. You can avoid it
> by removing provided from your pom as it's only
> necessary when building a war file that will be deployed to a servlet
> container.

I've removed the provided , ran a mvn clean (it does not work to just re-run the project) and then it worked.

Weird that this basic issue is still present in IntelliJ after 6 years (link is from 2016)

Answer (score 0):

Krowar's answer above solved my solution once I had invalidated caches and restarted the IDE.

Comment: please expand this into a standalone answer crediting the other answer for its partial contribution

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35705484)